# Java enum variable name same as enum name

Tags: java, enums

Can anyone explain why enum variable name cannot be same as enum name? If it was a regular class , it would work, but for some reason enum doesn't.
Example that does not work --> 
`someEnumType someEnumType = someEnumType.TYPE1;`

Comment: can you show us your enum please

Comment: What error message do you get? That should work. Variable names have some rules, but "it cannot be the name of an enum" is not one of them.

Comment: You just need to follow Java Code Convention and rename your class staring with capital letter

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? Does `Integer Integer = 1;` look like it's going to be easy to reason about?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I made a mistake by naming it the same , but when I saw that only enum cannot be named like that , I wanted to know why. Thats why I asked.

Answer (score 4):

See [JLS Sec 6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) (emphasis added) (*):

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the rest of the block in which the declaration appears, **starting with its own initializer** and including any further declarators to the right in the local variable declaration statement.

In

```
someEnumType someEnumType = someEnumType.TYPE1;
```

Java considers that the `someEnumType` on the right-hand side is referring to the variable, which hasn't been definitely assigned yet.

---

(*) One of the interesting consequences of this rule is that this is legal:

```
String s = s = "hello!";
```

(for those cases when you really really *really* want to assign a variable).

Comment: And to fix the issue, you can qualify the enum with the package. That will distinguish it from the variable: `someEnumType someEnumType = myPackage.someEnumType.TYPE1;`. (Or of course, write the enum name capitalized: `SomeEnumType`).